# Why setting index_col to zero shifts the first column heading by one row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0)
print(df)
```

The *data.csv* file contents are:

```
Reg. No, Score
 234, 78
 467, 98
 876, 23
 675, 49
 123, 56
```

This gives me the following weird output:

```
           Score
 Reg. No        
234           78
467           98
876           23
675           49
123           56
```

If I remove the `index_col` parameter or set it to `None` then both **Reg. No** and **Score** are aligned to the same row. But, for further processing of this data, I need the `index_col=0`.
How to get around this?

Comment: Because `Reg. No` is the index, and the index header is handled differently.  Why do you care?  You can't really be relying on pandas' default formatting for any production task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem here. That's just how a named index is printed. Cf.

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({'foo': list('abc'), 'bar': range(3)}).set_index('foo')
     bar
foo     
a      0
b      1
c      2
```